# How to search and extract a string from a string in PHP?

Tags: php, string, variables, search

I have a string variable which contains many information like address, names etc..
But, How to extract separately this information in PHP, for insert it in a database? For example:

```php
$string = 'Address : 123 Street Name : John';
```

And I expected:

```php
$name = 'John';
$address = '123 Street';
```

Comment: Please show us a larger string which might be containing this information.  There are some edge cases which you did not address.

Comment: This is a _really_ sh*tty “data format”, so please first of all slap the person that came up with this appropriately :-) The only way this _can_ be successfully parsed to begin with, is if all the keys are single words without any spaces in them (or are all known upfront) - otherwise, it would be impossible to determine here with the given example, whether this is supposed to be `Address: 123 Street` and `Name: John`, or maybe `Address: 123` and `Street Name: John`

Comment: You have different options, depending if you know by advance the keys you want to extract or not. Some clues are use of a regex, `substr`, `explode`.. But in your case if you don't know the keys it will be hard, as 04FS pointed out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `preg_match` function to match information you need into separate capture groups using Regular expression.

For your example variable we can do this:

```php
preg_match('/Address\s\:\s(.*)\sName\s\:\s(.*)/', $string, $matches);
```

Now, in `$matches` variable will be stored such data:

```php
array (
  0 => 'Address : 123 Street Name : John',
  1 => '123 Street',
  2 => 'John',
)
```

The first item of array is global capture of entire regular expression. And the next items stores manually captured data.

Then, create your variables:

```php
$address = $matches[1];
$name = $matches[2];
```

Comment: beat me to it (though I'd argue to handle the regex separately

Comment: I'm wondering why you added the conditionnal `?` for the second capturing group..

Comment: @Kaddath thanks, it was just mistake. It did't affects current result